# acts_as_taggable not filtering by tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I am following along the [acts_as_taggable](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast) screencast but cannot seem to get the tag pages to filter by tag (instead it just shows all the posts).
Here is my posts#index:

```
def index
if params[:tag]
 @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
 @posts = Post.order("created_at desc")   
end
end
```

my routes.rb:

```
 get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
```

the link to the tags page:

```
Tags: <%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

and the posts model:

```
acts_as_taggable
```

Comment: I guess that you're not sending params[:tag] to the controller. Can you check, if params[:tag] has any value? Also can you please post html generated by <%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>.

Comment: Sorry new to rails, how would i check if params[:tag] has any value. The HTML looks like <p>Tags: <a href="/tags/world">world</a></p>.

Comment: Are you using any debugger?

Comment: No, I am not using a debugger

Comment: Use one, it will really come in handy:). Try pry. Just add gem 'pry', to your gemfile, run bundle install and then you can halt code execution with binding.pry. Then you can examine variables in the terminal. So, install pry, add 'binding.pry' on the first line of your index action, and then just write params[:tag] into the terminal. It will show you its value.

Comment: Ok added but params[:tag] gives an error in the terminal.

Comment: What error? Can you post it please?:)

Comment: params[:tag]: command not found. I add binding.pry right after def index correct?

Comment: Okay, my bad. Stop the rails server, add line 'binding.pry' and make it first line of your index action, start rails server, try to filter by a tag, look into your terminal, into the window where Rails application server is running. You should see, that the execution stopped and it's waiting for you to write something. Write 'params[:tag]' in there and post what it had returned.

Comment: Ah ok got it. It returned 'world' which is the correct tag.

Comment: Ok, and what happens if you try to run 'Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])' in same terminal window? Does it return correct posts?

Comment: Yep it returns the correct post.

Comment: Uff, what happens if you visit directly url like 'localhost:3000/tags/world'? Btw you can resume code execution by typing exit into terminal...

Comment: The page stays the same.